# How to create Hot Spots for an image

Tags: c#, wpf, image, hyperlink

For a given document (will be a scanned document in an image format - likely .JPG or .PNG).  I need to be ale to draw hotspots on a document (might be a line, free form polygon, circle, ellipse, rectangle) and define the links.  the hotspot should highlight when the mouse is over the hotspot.  A given hot spot can have multiple links to other items that will be displayed in a context menu when the hot spot is clicked.

I can do this in winforms, but the result is raster based.  I need to know how to store and re-produce the objects vector based.  I also need to allow for transforms (rotation, zoom).  I cannot use WinForms for this project.

Comment: "_Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam._" But look up `Systems.Windows.Media.DrawingContext`

Comment: Look up LeadTools.  Not an open source library but I think it does what you are looking for.

Comment: Perhaps I should not have asked about libraries...  I have looked extensively at various classes.  I can generate the items in XAML by hand but I am at a loss for how to generate the objects based on mouse movements/clicks, how to save that info and generate later.  I can do it in WinForms, but that is not an option for me - I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was simple...  I needed to use ContentPresenter objects and place them at locations on a canvas.  I was able to store the "Path" data (including size, location, rotation, foreground, background, etc.) in an xml file.  As  I read the XML file, I create ContentPresenter object, assign the content as the generated Path (or other geometry), set the canvas top/left positions and add as a child of the canvas...

Maybe the question was badly worded.  Hopefully this helps someone else out.